# How should I binding value to make the labelView in CustomItemView show the text info in the listController?

Tags: sproutcore

I try to design a custom view inside a listView. 
The code looks like the following:

```
Myapp.listView=SC.ScrollView.design({
  layout: { centerX: 0, width:100, top: 70, bottom:36},
  contentView: SC.ListView.design({
    contentBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('Myapp.listController'),
    rowHeight: 36,
    exampleView:Myapp.CustomItemView.design({

         })

  })
});



MyApp.CustomItemView = SC.View.design({
          childViews:['imageView','labelView'],

          imageView: ....,
          labelView:SC.LabelView.design({

   })

});
```

My question is:
How should I binding value to make the labelView in CustomItemView show the text info in the listController?

Comment: In the labelView, try this:
valueBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('.parentView*content.textInfo')
...where textInfo is the name of your content's property that you want to display.  Give that a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ramesh say, your customItemView should be like this:

```
MyApp.CustomItemView = SC.View.design({
  childViews:['imageView','labelView'],

  imageView: ...
  labelView: SC.LabelView.design({
    valueBinding: ".parentView.content.textInfo"
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for answers.

While playing around yesterday, I ended up with this solution.

I made a generic view which rely on two properties (libelle = static text, valeur = dynamic text). Then I can create multiple views using the same pattern and just changing the "valeurBinding" property amongst all instances. Anyway, I'm not sure hacking the render function is the good way to do things, but it works at the moment.

```
MyFrameWork.LabelDataView = SC.View.extend
({
  libelle: '',
  valeur: '',
  render: function(context, firstTime) {

    context = context.begin('span').addClass('ldv-label').push(this.get('libelle') + ': ').end();
    context = context.begin('span').addClass('ldv-value').push(this.get('valeur')).end();

    sc_super();
  } 
});
```